Should we have the [iso] tag?
In a question asked not long ago, the iso tag was created. The tag referred to the International Organization for Standardization.
But the word ISO can have other meanings due to its widespread use, such as the ISO-9660 compact disc file system, as well as the ISO-12232 photography standard on light sensitivity and related topics.
Should we have an ISO tag? What meaning should it have?

The next question if we should also remove [tag:NIST] for the same reason, and possibly create tags such as [tag:standardization] and [tag:testing] (the current [tag:standard] tag could be made a pseudonym of [tag:standardization]). Let's see how this poll fares and create a follow-up if required!

I find it amusing that we're going to have a tag with the same name as that on [Photogeaphy.SE] but have contrasting (pun intended) meaning.

I don't think it is that illuminating to understand that a word can have multiple meanings (likewise).

Yes, we should have it. As it unambiguously refer to the Standards Developing Organization (SDO) almost all of the time.
Other tags can then indicate which family of standards are targeted, such as lightweight cryptography for the one ISO-tagged question.

On second thought, I think this is kind of parallel to the NIST tag, and that has 9 watchers and 179 questions, much more than that I expected. And I can see looking for PQC and NIST together is useful, for instance.

No we shouldn't have it. As said, it has multitude of meanings in other areas, and there doesn't exist a familiar instance of cryptography standard from ISO that most of the community members can immediately think of.
